# Unable to assert axis label text in highcharts using Geb

Tags: highcharts, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver, geb

I am writing a geb test that asserts the axis labels in a highcharts graph.

The test I wrote works when run with the selenium chrome driver. When I run with phantomjs it fails.

```
//Selector in GEB

$(id:"graph-id").find("g.highcharts-legend-item").find("tspan").text()
```

This returns as expected in Chrome. It returns empty in phantomjs.

We have to use phantomjs for our CI builds.

Comment: What is "g" by the way?

Comment: `g` is group in SVG.

Comment: Related: [Geb/Selenium selectors on SVG elements fail with certain versions of PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25693949/1816580)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for whatever reason geb isn't supporting your phantomjs driver properly, you can always execute a javascript selector directly through the browser:

```
def webElements = browser.driver.executeScript("""return document.querySelectorAll("#graph-id g.highcharts-legend-item tspan"); """)
def gebNavigators = webElements.collect{ new NonEmptyNavigator(browser, it) }
```

Which will give you a list of geb navigators which point to the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have phantomjs on my machine but can you please try this and update us whether it's working or not?

```
$("#graph-id .highcharts-legend-item").find("tspan").text()
```

Comment: If it is indeed right, please don't forget to reformulate your answer so that it is reads like an answer and not like a comment. Also, please elaborate why you think this solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the issue by reverting the version of phantomjs from 1.9.7 to 1.9.1
and the following library dependencies:

```
def seleniumVersion = "2.41.0"
def gebVersion = "0.9.0"

test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion"
test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
test( "com.github.detro.ghostdriver:phantomjsdriver:1.0.4" ) {
    transitive = false
}
```