# Selenium selectors on SVG TSPAN elements fail with certain versions of PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am using Geb and Selenium, and noticed that tests that reference certain SVG elements fail on certain PhantomJS versions.  This test running against the Highcharts demo site passes if I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.1, but fails on 1.9.7 - the SVG `tspan` element is successfully located (`size() > 0` passes) but `text()` returns empty string.

I have been able to isolate that the problem is not Geb specifically - I get the same problem when I interact with the `PhantomJSDriver` directly.

So I don't where to go next to troubleshoot this: is it a problem in the PhantomJS remote driver, or in PhantomJS itself?  How would I troubleshoot where the problem is?

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec;

class TspanSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

   def "tspan elements found but can't get text"() {
     when:
        go "http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked"

     then:
        waitFor { $("g.highcharts-axis").find("tspan").size() > 0 }
        $("g.highcharts-axis").find("tspan").text() == "Total fruit consumption"
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Unable to assert axis label text in highcharts using Geb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25668423/1816580)

Comment: try adding waitFor for the text too: waitFor { $("g.highcharts-axis").find("tspan").text() == "Total fruit consumption" }

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun nope, that just fails with same error 5 seconds later.

Comment: This also fails in Chrome. What makes you think that it should work in PhantomJS? You are stuck with an old version of PhantomJS. Alternatively, you could try SlimerJS.

Comment: @ArtjomB. it passed on Chrome for me.

Comment: Linked defect on GhostDriver page https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12813

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround: retrieve text with jQuery object instead of WebElement.

```
$("g.highcharts-axis").find("tspan").jquery.text() == "Total fruit consumption"
```